# String update for each group in data frame

Tags: r

I have a large data frame `df` like this:

```
 firstname = c("John L",  "Robert C", "John", "J L", "Tom F", "T F", "Tom")
 lastname = c("Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Frost", "Frost", "Frost")
 id = c(178, 649, 384, 479, 539, 261, 347)
 df = data.frame(firstname, lastname, id)
```

Which looks as below in `df` view:

```
 firstname   lastname   id
  John L      Doe       178
  Robert C    Doe       649
  John        Doe       384
  J L         Doe       479
  Tom F       Frost     539
  T F         Frost     261
  Tom         Frost     347
```

As you see, the firstname in data frame is inconsistent. Sometime it is just an initial for example. I would like to have consistent firstname. I would like to have an output data frame like this:

```
 firstname   lastname   id
  John L      Doe       178
  Robert C    Doe       649
  John L      Doe       384
  John L      Doe       479
  Tom F       Frost     539
  Tom F       Frost     261
  Tom F       Frost     347
```

I have tried few approaches like grouping by lastname and then getting longest string for each group and then updating firstname in the if elseif statement by matching with other firstname in the group using below

```
  > sapply(strsplit("John L Doe"," "), function(a) paste(a[1],a[3]))
   [1] "John Doe"
  > sapply(strsplit("John L Doe"," "), function(a) paste(substr(a[1],1,1),a[2],a[3]))
   [1] "J L Doe"
```

It did not work as I realized taking a longest string in the group is not a good approach.

Mapping from initials of the `firstname` to the full form of `firstname` is always going to be correct. For example, there will be "John L Doe". But, he will have 3 variants in his `firstname`. For example, "John L", "John", and "J L". It is because these are list of authors on a very narrow subjects. There is a just inconsistencies in the formatting of the name which I would like to fix. Having one consistent name will help me to do more analysis on a wider scale.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: In the context of your real-world problem, how would you know that John and John L refer to the same person? If I have a Jack L Doe, who would J L Doe map to?

Comment: Are there people with same last names and if you match initials of first names to convert to long form do you know they are mapping to correct person? Edited to say @waterling stated my concern more clearly.

Comment: @waterling My data frame is narrow on the subject at hand. So, all the time, for example, J L Doe would map to John L Doe and not to Jack L Doe

Comment: @R.S. There are some people with same last name. That is why I included one example of it.  When I am matching the initial of first names to convert to long form, they are mapping to correct person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution produces your expected result, but bear in mind if Jack L Doe and John L Doe exist, J L Doe will map to the first longest name.

```
  firstname = c("John L",  "Robert C", "John", "J L", "Tom F", "T F", "Tom", "Jack L", "Robert Can","R C", "R C")
  lastname = c("Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Doe", "Frost", "Frost", "Frost", "Doe","Frost","Doe", "Frost")
  id = c(178, 649, 384, 479, 539, 261, 347,100,200,300,400)
  df = data.frame(firstname, lastname, id,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df$Initials <- sapply(strsplit(as.vector(firstname), " "), function(x) paste(substr(x, 1,1), collapse=""))
  df$LongName<-apply(df,1,function(x) {
    if(sub("\\s","",x[["firstname"]]) == x[["Initials"]]){
      choices<-df$firstname[ grepl(x[["Initials"]], df$Initials) & df$lastname == x[["lastname"]]]
    }
    else{
      choices<-df$firstname[ grepl(x[["Initials"]], df$Initials) & grepl(x[["firstname"]], df$firstname) & df$lastname == x[["lastname"]]] 
    }

    choices[which.max(nchar(choices))]
    }
  )
```

Result

```
  > df
  firstname lastname  id Initials   LongName
  1      John L      Doe 178       JL     John L
  2    Robert C      Doe 649       RC   Robert C
  3        John      Doe 384        J     John L
  4         J L      Doe 479       JL     John L
  5       Tom F    Frost 539       TF      Tom F
  6         T F    Frost 261       TF      Tom F
  7         Tom    Frost 347        T      Tom F
  8      Jack L      Doe 100       JL     Jack L
  9  Robert Can    Frost 200       RC Robert Can
  10        R C      Doe 300       RC   Robert C
  11        R C    Frost 400       RC Robert Can
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is usually done with a dictionary matching every spelling variant to a preferred name. There are smart solutions out there based on text similarity and text mining. Except if you already have the dictionary linking c("JL", J L", J.L.", etc....) to John L. I would not do it in R.

Have a look at [DataWrangler](http://vis.stanford.edu/wrangler/), [Trifacta](https://www.trifacta.com), [Dataiku](https://www.dataiku.com) or [Openrefine](http://openrefine.org) they all have a free version that will do what you are looking for. I know that Openrefine (was GoogleRefine before) can be scripted.

Answer (score 1):

Your usecase is not entirely clear.
As mentioned, there are issues if you have people with same last name, same initial but different first name. If you are convinced that this will never be the case in your data, then the solution may be quite simple.

However, if what you're trying to do is to find out if the names refer to the same people, you'll need a lot more, and that means diving into the subject of **Entity Reconciliation**.

There are some neat R packages for this (I've worked on a project involving entity reconciliation) including `RecordLinkage`, but the bottom line is: if you want reliable record linkage, you'll need at least a little more than first name & last name

Comment: Mapping will be correct all the times. It is because the list of firstname and lastname is focused on very narrow subject. I am aware that solution might be quite simple R code.